# Android : Copying a file to the internal storage. File not found

Tags: java, android, file, outputstream

I'm trying to backup my database file on the internal storage :

```
File fromFile = new File(context.getDatabasePath("database.db").getPath());
FileChannel fromFileChannel = new FileInputStream(fromFile).getChannel();

File toFile = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/database.db");
if (toFile.getParentFile() != null)
    toFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
FileChannel toFileChannel = new FileOutputStream(toFile).getChannel();

Log.i("LOG",fromFileChannel.transferTo(0, fromFileChannel.size(), toFileChannel)+"");

fromFileChannel.close();
toFileChannel.close();
```

The log returns "69632" without any error, so it looks like it worked.

The problem is that I can't find the file. And the /Android/data folder doesn't contain a folder with my app package name. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
File toFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "Android/data" + File.separator + context.getPackageName() + File.separator + "/database.db");

context.getFilesDir() will give you the directory private to your app, so the files in that will not be available to other apps.
```